# WPF IsMouseOver is always false though IsHitTestVisible == true

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm making a graphical editor using WPF and I am implementing a click-like switch between objects.

My graphical editor is quite specific because I actually draw such things called "Images" - they are `Canvas` instances inside `Border` instances, and then user is able to draw all the stuff (called figures) ONLY INSIDE these Images. All Images are added to initial canvas.

So there can be any number of Images on one initial canvas as well as any number of figures within a single Image, but there is only one current Image and one current figure and all the operations are applied to them.

Initial canvas basically look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plp4p.png).

Rectangles are images, triangles - figures inside them, elements in bold are 'current'

I faced a problem that `UIElement` instances added to initial  canvas during execution always have `IsMouseOver == false` despite `IsHitTestVisible == true` for all elements and canvas itself. Background is set for all elements.

The problem is that neither images or elements inside them have `IsMouseOver == true`.

---

*Code that adds Image to canvas.*

```
StartAction = (Point mouseDownPosition) =>
{
    _firstPoint = mouseDownPosition;
    _image = new Border() {
        Height = 0,
        Width = 0,
        Background = Brushes.Transparent
    };

    Canvas.SetLeft(_image, mouseDownPosition.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(_image, mouseDownPosition.Y);
    _subject.Canvas.Children.Add(_image);
    _subject.CurrentImage = _image;
};

ContinueAction = (Point currentCursorPosition) =>
{
    double width = currentCursorPosition.X - _firstPoint.X;
    double height = currentCursorPosition.Y - _firstPoint.Y;
    if (width >= 0)
        _image.Width = width;
    else
    {
        _image.Width = Math.Abs(width);
        Canvas.SetLeft(_image, _firstPoint.X + width);
    }
    if (height >= 0)
        _image.Height = height;
    else
    {
        _image.Height = Math.Abs(height);
        Canvas.SetTop(_image, _firstPoint.Y + height);
    }
};

FinishAction = (mouseUpPosition) =>
{
    if (_image.Width == 0 || _image.Height == 0 ||
            _image.BorderThickness.Left + _image.BorderThickness.Right >= _image.Width ||
            _image.BorderThickness.Top + _image.BorderThickness.Bottom >= _image.Height)
    {
        _subject.Canvas.Children.Remove(_image);
    }
    else
    {
        _image.Child = new Canvas()
        {
            Width = _image.Width - _image.BorderThickness.Left - _image.BorderThickness.Right,
            Height = _image.Height - _image.BorderThickness.Top - _image.BorderThickness.Bottom,
            Background = Brushes.Transparent,
            ClipToBounds = true,
            IsHitTestVisible = true
        };
        _subject.CurrentImage = _image;
    }
    // we reset variables
    Reset();
};
```

`StartAction` is invoked on `MouseDown`, `ContinueAction` - on `MouseMove`, `FinishAction` - on `MouseUp`.
`_subject` is instance of Model class, `_image` is `Border` instance, used in `ImageDrawingState` class.

*Code that should switch current image and/or current figure.*

```
FinishAction = (mouseUpPosition) =>
{
    var images = _subject.Canvas.Children;
    Border image = null;
    for (int i = images.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        image = images[i] as Border;
        if (image != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Image {0}", image.IsMouseOver);
            var position = Mouse.GetPosition(image);
            if (image.IsMouseOver)
                    break;
        }
        image = null;
    }
    if (image != null)
    {
        _subject.CurrentImage = image;
        var figures = (image.Child as Canvas).Children;
        Shape figure = null;
        for (int i = figures.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            figure = figures[i] as Shape;
            Debug.WriteLine("Figure {0}", figure.IsMouseOver);
            if (figure != null)
            {
                if (figure.IsMouseOver)
                    break;
            }
            figure = null;
        }
        if (figure != null)
            _subject.CurrentFigure = figure;
    }
};
```

I tried to make simulate the situation in not so complex environment and it works well.

*XAML:*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas Name="Canvas" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <Label Name="Label" Canvas.Right="100" Canvas.Bottom="20">Nope</Label>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

*Code behind:*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Dictionary<bool, string> _labelValues = new Dictionary<bool, string>()
    {
        {false, "Nope" },
        {true, "Yep" }
    };
    Canvas _canv;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Border border = new Border()
        { Width = 100, Height = 100, BorderBrush = Brushes.Red, BorderThickness = new Thickness(2),
        IsHitTestVisible = true};
        _canv = new Canvas() { Width = 100, Height = 100, Background = Brushes.Transparent };
        border.Child = _canv;
        Canvas.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        Canvas.MouseUp += Listener;
        Canvas.Children.Add(border);
    }

    private void Listener(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Label.Content = _labelValues[_canv.IsMouseOver];
        Debug.WriteLine(_canv.IsMouseOver);
    }
}
```

**So what can affect `IsMouseOver` behaviour in my original program?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean, other than the mouse?

Comment: @hoodaticus, I mean what other properties can affect mouse interraction. Because in simple example everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was by mouse captured by basic canvas previously, so mouse always was over it and NOT over children.

After releasing `MouseCapture` problem was fixed.